# How do you differentiate between QVD source files and target files when reading a QVW's XML MetaData?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, data-lineage

I am currently trying to find an alternative to the Governance Dashboard that Rob Wunderlich (Qlik founder) created, since I am currently encountering errors when using it.

How do you differentiate between a data source (QVD, aka source) that is used by a QVW or a data file (QVD, aka target) that is generated by that QVW?

```
QVW:
LOAD
    Lower(Discriminator) AS DataFile.Filepath
FROM C:\Sample_Transform_file.qvw (xmlSimple, Table is[DocumentSummary/LineageInfo])
```

Below is an example of what I found when parsing through the XML Metadata 
(discriminator subtag within the lineageinfo tag) for one specific Transform QVW.

[Sample Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if90Y.png)

Are targets just identified by this?

```
STORE - [qvdName.qvd](qvd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have found, That appears to be the case, to a degree.

All of our QVW files that output a QVD utilize DIRECTORY statements rather than either hard-coded file location paths or variablized paths. Hence why all of the Targets are getting displayed as "STORE - qvdname.qvd", instead of displaying the filepath. In a sense, that is a flaw on QlikView's part, regarding its Governance Dashboard (or at the very least, they don't seem to recommend variablizing those paths as a standard in order to avoid breaking the lineage).